# How to create Glass GDK project in IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-gdk

So far I could not find a solution to create Google Glass GDK project in IDEA, but I have to create it via Eclipse following [steps](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start)

> Click File > New Project > Android Sample Project
>   Select Glass Development Kit as the build target and click Next.
>   Select the Compass, Stopwatch, or Timer sample and click Finish.
>   ...

And then I import this project into IDEA.

How can we use GDK templates in IDEA? Is there a hack or alternative to Eclipse's `New Project > Android Sample Project`?

Answer (score 0):

- Using the SDK Manager install the SDK 19, and "Glass development kit preview"

  - Create a new project in IntelliJ, Android/Graddle: Android module.
  - Minimum and target api = 19
  - Compile with = Glass development kit preview

[More details here](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/84081134683/ide-imports-part-3-gradle-gdk-with-intellij)

Answer (score -1):

if you are familiar with Git, all of the same google glass sample project's and more are on their github repo.

https://github.com/googleglass

you can clone by going to your terminal and grabbing the individual projects.

```
git clone git@github.com:googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample.git
```

or visit the url and download the zip of the project

IE for stopwatch:https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample

you can import as normal after you clone or if IDEA supports GIT

If you have Android Developer Tools already properly downloaded, and glass sneak peak, make sure this is what your 'project properties' says

```
# Project target.
  target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15
```